# Duplicating a scaled version of one display's output on another in Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, graphics-card, multiple-monitors, lcd

I have a multi-monitor configuration attached to a machine running Windows 7 that consists of:

- 1 x 24" LCD - connected on DVI; main monitor
- 1 x ~100" projector - connected separately on DVI on a separate graphics card

What I'd like to do is have some way of displaying a *scaled* version of what's on the projector on the main LCD monitor - in a application window - preferably without additional hardware.

The two monitors are configured as separate displays via Windows without issue, with one being "next" to the other.  Physically, the LCD monitor sits at a control desk, whilst the projector is mounted overhead, some distance away.  Having something like a scalable window display of the projector output on the control monitor would aid me in positioning content.

Something like the simple Magnify tool built into Windows is nearly perfect except the shape of the window can't be resized and that it forces you to configure a focal point (cursor, keyboard, etc).

Is there some form of similar software out there that might handle this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to use [Open Broadcaster Software](https://obsproject.com/).  The software allows capture from a variety of input sources, including monitor capture, window capture, video capture devices, and more.  In this specific instance, monitor capture is the answer and OBS affords various different options to configure capture.

Now, whilst this software primarily is for the streaming or recording of input sources, it also allows a user to preview the input live.  In practical terms, this means being able to monitor input from a display output - exactly what is required.  The preview is scaled to the size of the OBS window, and OBS allows for a "projection" of the preview onto a dedicated monitor as well.

It runs on Windows (32 bit and 64 bit) though OBS Studio is in the works for other platforms.

As a side note, VLC's DirectShow capture is potentially another option and it does work, but given no specific configuration to capture just one monitor, setting it up is much more difficult.